# Множество Cookie от airpush

Tags: php, javascript

Возникла проблема с рекламной системой airpush.
Их скрипт, для каждого `url` устанавливает пользователю `cookie`. В итоге собирается огромное количество `cookie`, что в итоге вызывает ошибку

> 400 Bad Request

http://ab.airpush.com/apportal/v2/cdn/airpush.js

Решение с `LimitRequestFieldSize 16384` помогает но надолго ли его хватит.

Может кто сталкивался с проблемой?

Answer (score 2):

Раз куки на вашей стороне, значит Вы можете вручную их удалять.

Comment: В каком смысле вручную? Пользователь не будет очищать куки.

Comment: На стороне сервера, через PHP

Comment: есть множество кук под именами http%3A%2F%2Fdomain/script.php%3Fid=1 http%3A%2F%2Fdomain/script.php%3Fid=2 и тд Как их лучше всего удалять на стороне сервера?

Comment: PHP имеет доступ к кукам через супер глобальный массив $_COOKIE. Значит есть возможность пройти по этому массиву и по имени куки выбрать те, которые необходимо удалить. Удаление куки через setcookie().